# Search layout lookup dialog REST access

Tags: rest-api, page-layout, search-layout

I am able to look up search result search layouts via REST using the /search/layout/q=Account endpoint. But I would like to also read the lookup dialog search layout, like what you see on the web under Setup->Customize->Account->Search Layouts "Lookup Dialogs".

I've been googling with no success, and am guessing there is no REST API access of these layouts but if anyone knows different, please let me know. 
thanks!